# individual greek letters in chart legend that comes from a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts, symbols, greek

I'm creating a Weibull plot in Excel 2010. Each line on the chart needs a legend of this form:

my 1st data [n=250, b=2.401]     { where "b" should really be a lowercase Greek beta }

my 2nd line [n=331, b=2.395]     { where "b" should really be a lowercase Greek beta }

...

For the sake of example, let's say "my 1st data" is found in cells A2:B20 (x values in column A, y values in column B), and the title for that data is in cell B1 as follows:

="my 1st data [n="&text(nval,"#")&", b="&text(beta,"#.###")&"]"

Therefore, to plot "my 1st data" my chart contains this series:

=SERIES(B1,A2:A20,B2:B20)

I can format the "b" in the formula in cell B1 such that it appears as the Greek letter (lowercase) beta. (Even that's a bit tricky, but I can do it, and the result of the formula looks perfect when viewed in cell B1 directly.)

Here's the problem: on the chart itself, the legend apparently overrides the formatting of individual characters, and everything reverts to the default font in the legend. Obviously I can't format the entire cell as "Symbol" font, because then everything in the legend turns into symbols, which is even worse. Can somebody tell me if they've figured out how to to this?

Thanks,

Roger

Answer (score 1):

Many Unicode fonts include the Greek alphabet so you don't need to use the Symbol font in this case.

Window's inbuilt **Character Map** application will help you locate it and copy it to the clipboard. You can then paste it into Excel or any other application.

[image: Windows Character Map]

Comment: Mike, Thanks! I'd tried other sources of the beta character (for instance, from the "insert symbol" menu within Excel itself), but not the built-in Character Map from the OS. The problem with doing it from inside Excel is that once the formula is created, you lose access to the Insert menu; also, even when I found sources that displayed correctly in the formula (e.g. the Symbol font), they may be reinterpreted when the formula is retranslated into the legend. But copying it from the Character Map did the trick! Thanks!